# Can i have my RasPI to work with two seperate SD cards

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, raspberry-pi-os, kali

Is it possible to have the kali os and rasbian os on two separate SD cards and use both of them on the raspberry pi by switching the cards time after time.

This just simply came to my mind :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Just make sure you shutdown, power off, swap sd card, power on.